# DLL-s using C++ on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I have tried to find how to create DLL-s on linux using google, but got very confusing information.

Is it possible to write dynamic link libraries on linux? If not, are there other means by which I can call code in another module from several running programs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because DLL is a Windows term. In Linux they are called shared libraries.

http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 8):

As [Sklivvz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145771/dlls-using-c-on-linux#145779) has said, the term you're after on linux is shared object. These are given the file extension `.so`.

Using gcc you can create a `.so` by using the `-shared` option.

eg.

```
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.c
```

If you name your shared object lib*.so you can compile against it by using the `-l` option on your linker. Note that the "lib" is inferred in this circumstance.

ie.

```
ld -o a.out -lfoo someobject.o
```

Alternatively you can load `.so` files at runtime, just as you can with `.dll`s, using dlopen() and dlsym().

Answer (score 1):

It is a *lot* if you are just getting started, but at some point you will need to refer to Ulrich Drepper’s “[How To Write Shared Libaries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).”

Comment: A very interesting document. Essential if you're writing a major library framework, or if you have a problem with startup time, otherwise probably not useful, though still worth reading if you're the sort of person who likes to understand what's really going on.

Answer (score -1):

I guess .SO files instead of DLL files, meaning shared object, not StackOverflow :), is what you want.